# How to remove message after modal is closed in php

Tags: php

I have a small sample code where I display modal if I click the login button, and close the modal if I click anywhere in the background.

Now what I want to do is remove the error message for when the modal is closed so that when I open the modal again by clicking the login button, the message is removed. However the error message remains. What would be the best way to clear the message on when the modal is closed?

```
 <?php
    
    $username_err = "";
    
    // Processing form data when form is submitted
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
     
     if ($_POST["Login"]){
    
    //The if statement below would handle incorrect user crednetial entry but not included in code
    if(...code to check if username is incorrect){
    $username_err = "Username Error";
    }
    
    }
    
    <div id="id01" class="modal">
     <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
     <button type="submit" value="Login" name="Login">Enter</button>
    </div>

    
            <script>
            // Get the modal
            var modal = document.getElementById('id01');
            
            // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
            window.onclick = function(event) {
                if (event.target == modal) {
                    modal.style.display = "none";
                    <?php $username_err = ""; ?>
                }
            }
            
            </script>
```

Tried this with no luck

```
<?php if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
            if ($_POST["Login"]){
            echo "<script>
            document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block';
            document.getElementsByClassName('help-block').style.display='none';
}
            </script>";
```

Comment: I think you are confused between frontend and backend. Look like you don't store the error message anywhere and only generate and display it on each request. Just simply hide/remove the `<span>` where you display the error message when you close the modal using javascript.

Comment: Oh ok, let me give that a go

Comment: Hmmm.. it didn't seem to work. Included it on hiding and showing the block but doesn't seem to work. Here is example code I tried...

Comment: `<?php if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
            if ($_POST["Login"]){
            echo "<script>
            document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block';
            document.getElementsByClassName('help-block').style.display='none';}
            </script>";`

Comment: If there's only 1 `help-block`, try with `document.getElementsByClassName('help-block')[0].style.display='none';` ... or alternatively, the shorter: `document.querySelector('.help-block').style.display='none';`